# Drawing a Panels Handle to a Bitmap

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, mpv

I have a WPF-Application which hosts a WinformsPanel

```
<WindowsFormsHost>
    <windowsForms:Panel 
        x:Name="PlayerHost">
    </windowsForms:Panel>
<WindowsFormsHost>
```

I then use this Panel to display a video. I'm using [Mpv.NET](https://github.com/hudec117/Mpv.NET-lib-) lib to do this.
The video player is initialized properly:

```
//panel.Handle is the windowsForms:Panel named PlayerHost 
player = new MpvPlayer(panel.Handle, Common.IO.FindLib.FindMpvLib(binaryPath));
player.Load(videoFilePath);
```

Now, if I try to draw the panels content, the resulting image remains blank. The code to draw the image is as follows:

```
using (var bmp = new Bitmap(panel.ClientSize.Width, panel.ClientSize.Height))
{
    panel.DrawToBitmap(bmp, panel.ClientRectangle);
    bmp.Save(@"Some:\path.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
}
```

To make it clear: The video gets displayed. I can see the video content. And I start drawing to an image when the media is properly loaded. I even offloaded the drawing command to a button click. So while the video was running I tried to take a "frame capture" so to say. But the image remains blank.

How can I capture the panels content? Has it something to do with the native Handle being provided to the video player? Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, you can show video directly in a WPF form - you don't need to host a Forms panel for that. --- There's no information here about how you actually attempt to capture a frame.

Comment: You mean the media element? Mpv seems more robust to me with a larger variety of supported codecs. The last part displays the capturing. The video is rendered onto the panel and my idea, saving the panels content to a bitmap, doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the panels content to a bitmap with the following code:

```cs
using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(panel.Width, panel.Height))
{
    panel.DrawToBitmap(b, new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height));
    b.Save("test.png");
}
```

Comment: That is exactly, what I've tried and what did not work in this context.